# remove CRLF in the last line

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops

How to remove the last `crlf` code below?

```
  Dim fh As StreamReader
  Dim temp as string
  Dim temp1 as string
  fh = new StreamReader("haggis.txt")
  Dim s As String = fh.ReadLine()
  While not s Is Nothing

    temp = temp & s & Vbcrlf

  Console.WriteLine(temp)

  End While
  fh.Close()
```

haggis.txt

```
AAAA   
BBBB


'Return 
AAAA
BBBB
crlf  <---- I want to remove this.
```

Comment: Your code is totally invalid.

Comment: I change the code SLaks - tnx

Comment: Was I the only one who found "haggis.txt" amusing?

Comment: you could also use a regular expression to remove the last clrf in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do direct `String` concatenation in a loop. I realize the above code is also just an example, but you never update `s` inside of your loop, and thus it will be an infinite loop if it enters it.

Assuming you fix that, you want to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) for the `String` concatenation:

```
Dim temp As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

While s IsNot Nothing

    temp.Append(s).Append(vbCrLf)

End While

Dim answer As String = ""

' avoid trying to get a substring if it's blank
If temp.Length <> 0 Then

    answer = temp.ToString(0, temp.Length - vbCrLf.Length)

End If
```

To get it without the last vbCrLf, simply chop it off as I do above.

Comment: there is one exception to stringBuilder in that it should not be used when concatenating string constants like "abc" + "def".

Comment: @Mark Hosang Fair point. It should not be used when concatenating constants because they will be concatenated together by the compiler rather than at runtime. The same goes for Java (in case anyone finds this from searching).

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead: use [`File.ReadAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx#Y921) so that you don't have to use a `vbCrLf` at all. It loads all lines into a string array.

```
 Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines("haggis.txt")
 Dim s As String
 For Each s In readText
     Console.WriteLine(s)
 Next
```

Comment: For small files this solution is ok but don't you think that it will fail on large files

Comment: @Subhash: take all code you find on the internets with a grain of salt, and measure against your particular requirements. :) How much memory do you have on your hypothetical server?

Comment: I am just asking this for my knowledge. How much large file is safe to use with File.ReadAllLines() cause I have been stuck in some situations while using this. It will be very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

**This could be an easy solution**

```
    For Each 
        Do
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strline)) Then
                strline = strline & objSR.ReadLine()
            Else
                strline = vbCrLf & objSR.ReadLine()
            End If
            objwriteline.strline()
        Loop
    Next
```

Comment: `IIf` is a function in VB, and VB.NET. It is not equivalent to the ternary operator in C#. As a result, the `IIf` will result in objSR.ReadLine() being called twice, thus skipping half of the file (every odd line, with the possible exception of the last). The `If` "operator" was introduced in VB.NET 2008 to act like the C# ternary operator (`?:`). For example: `If(boolean_expression, true_part, false_part)`

Comment: @pickypg as adviced by you i have changed the code. Please feel free to comment

Comment: As-is, that solution will not work. If the file is blank, then this will crash (due to the If statement assigning a value to `Nothing`/`null`). If it comes in and it is _not_ blank or `Nothing`, then it will _never_ be blank or nothing again because you keep appending the remainder of the file to it. So, if it comes in as `True`, then it will crash immediately. If it comes it as `False`, then the vbCrLf will be appended upon every read.